# set.seed() in quanteda's lda function

Tags: r, lda, quanteda

Each time I run this code, I get a different result:

```
set.seed(42)
lda_seq <- textmodel_lda(dfmt, k = 5, gamma = 0.5, 
    batch_size = 0.01, auto_iter = TRUE,
    verbose = FALSE)

terms(lda_seq)
```

The package is from seededlda based on quanteda.

How can I get reproducible results?

I tried different seeds, but the results will be completely different each time I run the code with the same seed. Note, there is no link between the set.seed() function and seededlda package.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `options(seededlda_threads = 1)` gives reproducible results:

(It is unclear in the documentation how one can set a seed for each of the sub-processes when multi-threading so, as r2evans suggests in the comments, it may be worth raising this as a [Github issue](https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda/issues).)

```r
library(quanteda)
library(seededlda)

options(seededlda_threads = 1)

corp <- data_corpus_moviereviews
toks <- tokens(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, 
               remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_url = TRUE)

dfmt <- dfm(toks) |> 
  dfm_remove(stopwords("en")) |>
  dfm_remove("*@*") |>
  dfm_trim(max_docfreq = 0.1, docfreq_type = "prop")

set.seed(42)
lda_seq <- textmodel_lda(dfmt, k = 5, gamma = 0.5, 
                         batch_size = 0.01, auto_iter = TRUE,
                         verbose = FALSE)

x <- terms(lda_seq)

set.seed(42)
lda_seq <- textmodel_lda(dfmt, k = 5, gamma = 0.5, 
                         batch_size = 0.01, auto_iter = TRUE,
                         verbose = FALSE)

y <- terms(lda_seq)

waldo::compare(x, y)
#> ✔ No differences
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-30 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't see clear wording in the package (documentation or code) that discusses the impact "multiple threads" has on random seeds. In fact, I see many uses of `set.seed(.)` in the package unit tests without changing this option. What made you test this? Did you confirm the OP's problem with other `_threads` values? Do you think this is a bug (or under-documentation) in the package?

Comment: Yes, it gives different results with `seededlda_threads = 2`. The documentation mentions "User can change the number of sub-processes used for the parallel computing via options(seededlda_threads)" and I suspected it may be the root cause.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that mention of `_threads` in the documentation, but no reference to it impacting threads. I don't doubt the results, it's not uncommon for multi-threaded apps to not correctly use random seeds from the parent process/thread. Might I suggest two things? (1) you (Carl) add just a little bit of explanation to your answer that suggests why this is a factor; and (2) either of you (Carl or @DanD) submit a [feature request](https://github.com/koheiw/seededlda/issues) that either adds documentation (for seeds) or better yet uses the seeds correctly in multi-threaded use. (Just a thought.)